# CSStudent Class

Tags: java

```
public class CSStudent 
{
String[] requiredGeneralClasses = {"biology", "calculus", "chemistry", "english", "physics", "psychology", "economics"};
String[] requiredInMajorClasses = {"algorithms", "data structures", "numerical analysis", "graphics", "databases"};
String[] completedClasses;
int[] gradeForCompletedClasses;
String[] inCompleteClasses;
int count = 0;

public CSStudent()
{
    completedClasses = new String[1000];
    gradeForCompletedClasses = new int[1000];
    inCompleteClasses = new String[1000];
}

public void completeClass(String classs /*class*/, int gradeOnHundredPointScale)
{
    completedClasses[count] = classs;

    if(gradeOnHundredPointScale <= 100)
    {
        gradeForCompletedClasses[count] = gradeOnHundredPointScale;
    }
    count++;
}

public double getInMajorGPA()
{
    double inMajorGPA = 0;
    double numberOfInMajorClassesCompleted = 0;
    double gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(completedClasses[i].equals(requiredInMajorClasses[0]) || completedClasses[i].equals(requiredInMajorClasses[1]) || completedClasses[i].equals(requiredInMajorClasses[2]) || completedClasses[i].equals(requiredInMajorClasses[3]) || completedClasses[i].equals(requiredInMajorClasses[4]))
        {
            numberOfInMajorClassesCompleted++;
            if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 93.50 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] <= 100)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  4.0;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 90 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 93.50)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  3.7;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 86.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 90)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  3.3;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 83.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 86.5)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  3.0;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 80 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 83.5)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  2.7;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 76.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 80)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  2.3;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 73.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 76.5)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  2.0;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 70 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 73.5)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  1.7;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 66.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 70)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  1.3;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 63.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 66.5)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  1.0;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 60 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 63.5)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  0.70;
            }
            else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 60)
            {
                gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses +=  0;
            }
        }
    }
    inMajorGPA = gradeForCompletedInMajorClasses/numberOfInMajorClassesCompleted;
    return inMajorGPA;
}

public double getOverallGPA()
{
    double overallGPA = 0;
    double gradeForAllCompletedClasses = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 93.50 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] <= 100)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  4.0;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 90 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 93.50)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  3.7;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 86.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 90)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  3.3;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 83.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 86.5)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  3.0;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 80 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 83.5)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  2.7;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 76.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 80)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  2.3;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 73.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 76.5)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  2.0;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 70 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 73.5)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  1.7;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 66.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 70)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  1.3;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 63.5 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 66.5)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  1.0;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] > 60 && gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 63.5)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  0.70;
        }
        else if(gradeForCompletedClasses[i] < 60)
        {
            gradeForAllCompletedClasses +=  0;
        }
    }
    overallGPA = gradeForAllCompletedClasses/count;
    return overallGPA;
}

public String[] getAllIncompleteRequiredClasses()
{
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(!requiredGeneralClasses[0].equals(completedClasses[i]))
        {
            inCompleteClasses[counter] = requiredGeneralClasses[0];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return inCompleteClasses;
}

public String[] getAllIncompleteInMajorClasses()
{

}

public boolean hasCompletedAllRequiredClasses()
{
    boolean hasCompletedAllRequiredClasses = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(requiredGeneralClasses[0].equals(completedClasses[i]) && requiredGeneralClasses[1].equals(completedClasses[i]))
        {
            hasCompletedAllRequiredClasses = true;
        }
    }
    return hasCompletedAllRequiredClasses;
}
```

#### Tester

```
public class CSStudentTester 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    CSStudent student = new CSStudent();
    student.completeClass("biology", 75);
    student.completeClass("algorithms", 95);
    student.completeClass("physics", 89);
    student.completeClass("data structures", 85);
    System.out.println("InMajor GPA: " + student.getInMajorGPA());
    System.out.println("Overall GPA: " + student.getOverallGPA());

    for(int i = 0; i < student.count; i++)
    {
    System.out.println(student.getAllIncompleteRequiredClasses()[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(student.hasCompletedAllRequiredClasses());
}
}
```

I have this class and I problems with 2 methods:

1. for the getAllIncompleteRequiredClasses method I am supposed to print all the required classes that are not completed. I am using print statements just to see if that is correct. But I don't want it to print dkl because that requiredGeneralClasses[4] (that is physics) has already been called in the tester class(see above).  What is it that I am doing wrong?
2. For the `public boolean hasCompletedAllRequiredClasses()` method it should return true when I call the following methods because all the required classes are there. But when I try it, it returns false. Why is it printing false?

#### Code:

```
 student.completeClass("calculus", 75);
student.completeClass("chemistry", 95);
student.completeClass("english", 89);
student.completeClass("psychology", 75);
student.completeClass("economics", 95);
```

Comment: It is better to ask one question at a time.  Is this [tag:homework]?

Comment: it is optional. But I really want to do this.

Comment: Are you saying it is optional homework, or optional for us to answer the 2nd question?  Please try to understand that we are not psychic, and it is therefore a good idea to add a few more words (that will explain a statement), than a few less (that just leads to more questions).

Comment: no the homework is optional but I want to complete the coding.

Comment: Please add the [tag:homework] to homework questions, even if they are optional or extra credit homework.  It is advantageous to do so, since a lot of helpful people watch that tag.

Comment: sorry I didn't know that I am new to this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your function `getAllIncompleteRequiredClasses`  in the following way..I am assuming you want to print all the incomplete required classes(both general and major)

```
public String[] getAllIncompleteRequiredClasses()
{
    int counter = 0;
    boolean match =false;
    for(int k = 0; k < requiredGeneralClasses.length; k++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            //System.out.println(requiredGeneralClasses[k] + " "+ completedClasses[i]);
            if(requiredGeneralClasses[k].equalsIgnoreCase(completedClasses[i]))
            {
                match=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!match)
        {
            //inCompleteClasses[counter] = new String();
            inCompleteClasses[counter] = requiredGeneralClasses[k];
            counter++;
        }
        match = false;
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < requiredInMajorClasses.length; k++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            //System.out.println(requiredGeneralClasses[k] + " "+ completedClasses[i]);
            if(requiredInMajorClasses[k].equalsIgnoreCase(completedClasses[i]))
            {
                match=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!match)
        {
            inCompleteClasses[counter] = requiredInMajorClasses[k];
            counter++;
        }
        match = false;
    }
    return inCompleteClasses;
}
```

and your function `hasCompletedAllRequiredClasses` as

```
public boolean hasCompletedAllRequiredClasses()
{
     for(int i = 0; i < inCompleteClasses.length; i++)
        {
            if(inCompleteClasses[i]!=null)
                return false;
        }
     return true;
}
```

and of course you can optimize the code in a much better way.

Comment: and initialize your inCompleteClasses array as inCompleteClasses = new String[requiredGeneralClasses.length+requiredInMajorClasses.length]; and not new String[1000];

Comment: is there any way to not get null for the classes that are already completed?

Comment: You are getting null coz the array actually has more space allocated then it actually should be. So, for the rest of the elements we are getting null. You can either dynamically allocate space or use a null check just before using the elements.